# update ListView from another form

Tags: .net, vb.net, basic

I tried all methods by users here but none seems to work for me.
I want to update a ListView in Form1 from Form2 in vb.net but nothing happens when I launch this method.

```
Public Sub checkFoundList()
    For Each item In myListView.Items
        If Not File.Exists(item.SubItems(2).Text) Then
            myListView.Items.Remove(item)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This method is on Form1 and when I launch it here it works fine. But if I call it from Form2, it doesn't.

In Form2 I just call it with:

```
Form1.checkFoundList()
```

I tried also to put the modifier Public to `myListView` but still doesn't work. Also the methods explained by some users like using events doesn't work. Really weird.

Is ListView a special control?

Comment: "It doesnt work" is not very helpful. If that method is on FOrm1 with the listview it should work fine.  The problem may be using the default form instance.

Comment: As I said using it from Form1 works fine (e.g click on a button1 on Form1 calling that method works), if I call it from Form2 (e.g click on a button2 on Form2) it doesn't work. By doesn't work I mean nothing happens and no exception thrown.

Comment: Forgot to say... WinForms. Oh and if you give me C# is the same for me I can translate it to vb.

Comment: Please show how you call it from form2, as I said, the problem may be you are using the default form instance.

Comment: Ok, edited first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem you will have is you are modifying the items in the list as you are enumerating it with a `For Each` statement. This will cause problems when you delete an item.

Instead enumerate it with a `For` statement working *backwards* so the indexes don't shift when you are removing an item:

```
Public Sub checkFoundList()
    For i = myListView.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Dim item As <TypeTheListViewHolds> = myListView.Items(i)
        If Not File.Exists(item.SubItems(2).Text) Then
            myListView.Items.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I have just adapted the code you provided (without knowing what `myListView` holds), but the methodology would be the same regardless of the datatype.

With regards to calling it from `Form2`, make sure you are calling `checkFoundList` from an *instance of* `Form1`. Something like:

```
' Class variable in Form2 which has an instance of Form1.
Private _form1 As Form1

' New Form2 method.
' Pass an instance of Form1 to the constructor of Form2.
' This way this instance of Form2 will "know" about a Form1 object.
Public Sub New(form1Object As Form1)
   ' Initialization code.

   ' Set the reference to Form1 in Form2
   _form1 = form1Object
End Sub

Public Sub Form2Method()
    _form1.checkFoundList
End Sub
```

Comment: What's TypeTheListViewHolds?

Comment: @xpirt - Glad it worked. Regarding "TypeTheListViewHolds": your example wasn't clear what datatype/object `MyListView` was holding. So I just inserted that into my sample to show you should fill the appropriate type.

Comment: yeah later I understood xD. thank you again for your solution and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, it would be helpful to see the error you are getting. But it is most likely because Form2 doesn't have a reference to Form1. One of many ways to fix this is to set Form2's owner to Form1.

In Form1 when you create Form2 set its owner:

```
Dim f2 As Form2 = New Form2()
f2.Owner = Me
f2.ShowDialog()
```

In Form2 get a reference to Form1 and access the list box, in this case I access a simple text box:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim f1 As Form1 = DirectCast(Me.Owner, Form1)
    f1.TextBox1.Text = "Hello World"
End Sub
```

Comment: with the modifier `Public` on myListView it doesn't work... btw as I said no errors or exceptions are thrown, just nothing happens.

Comment: You may be swallowing the exception somewhere. To break on any exceptions, go to menu Debug -> Exceptions. In the Exception window  check the box in the "Thrown" column for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". Click "OK". Now debug run your app and see if you break on an exception.